# Index with ! in their name cant be filtered for recovering

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ES cluster whith indices name like `web.analytics.data.api!monthly!2018-07_v0` and doing regular snapshots/backups

Now, when I want to restore all of them, all works pretty well. If I want to restore just a specific index however, es wont do it. The command I use:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/_snapshot/s3_backups/20191218_060001/_restore?pretty&wait_for_completion=true" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "indices": "web.analytics.data.api!monthly!2018-07_v0",
  "index_settings": {
    "index.number_of_replicas": 0
  }
}
'
```

The result I get is:

```
{
  "snapshot" : {
    "snapshot" : "20191218_060001",
    "indices" : [ ],
    "shards" : {
      "total" : 0,
      "failed" : 0,
      "successful" : 0
    }
  }
}
```

Please note, that If I use index without `!` in its name (e.g. `.kibana`), it works well. Any ideas of how I can solve that? Preferably without telling developers to rename the indices. The ES in question has version `1.7.3` I am aware it is EOL, but it is what I have to work with right now.

Answer (score 0):

So it was my bad in the end. The index I got did not exist (typo in it) but I was told `!` is problematic so i did not double check and the test indices were picked by me, so of course they were correct...